# Change button text onclick with condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, viewbag, actionresult

My aim is to have a button, with default value Block and when the user click on it, it will change the text to Unblock and also after page refresh the text of the button must remain the same, if the text is changed to unblock then after refresh it must remain unblock.

What i have tried uptil now is this:

View code for Button:

```
input type="submit" value="@ViewBag.SubmitValue" id="Block" style="color: white; 
background-color: darkred; border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
border-top-left-radius: 2px; border-top-right-radius: 2px; padding: 4px 4px; 
border: none; padding-bottom:2px "
```

Controller ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Block(int Id, Block block, string userAction)
        {
            if(userAction ==  "Block")
            {
                ViewBag.SubmitValue = "Block";
            }
            if (userAction == "Unblock")
            {
                ViewBag.SubmitValue = "Unblock";
            }
          .....
        }
```

I am haivng issue in this passing string userAction in ActionResult, the value of userAction is passing as Null in the Method, so the text of button is not changing and it is showing "Submit" on button

Please help

Answer (score 0):

use a hidden input element named "userAction" and set its value to whatever you need.

```
<input type="hidden" name="userAction" value="@ViewBag.SubmitValue">
```

and for default action set the initialized value of userAction like this:

```
public ActionResult Block(string userAction = "Block", int Id, Block block){

    //...

}
```

whenever you passed nothing named userAction it will be set to "Block" not null

Comment: I have tried this, its not working, still the userAction is null even after assigning like this `userAction="Block"` and in View this is what i have done `<input type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="Block">
<input type="hidden" name="userAction" value="@ViewBag.SubmitValue">`

Comment: how are you calling the action? using form post or get?

Comment: using post, I am it using Ajax.beginform and this is my partial view  `<input type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="Block">
<input type="hidden" name="userAction" value="@ViewBag.SubmitValue">`  and the Main View code is: `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Block", "...", new { Id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "Post",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            }
        ))
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("Block", new Models.Block())
                    }`